# What classifier in machine learning could be better when I have class overlapping?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, overlap, overlapping

I have to predict from data that belongs to one of two classes, however, those classes overlaps (let's say a lot). I was wondering what classifier could give the best results based on someone else experience.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: By "overlapping", do you mean the classes are not linearly separable, or that it is possible that samples belong to both classes? I understood the latter interpretation, but I think Ami Tavory's answer assumes the first.

Comment: By overlapping I mean that classes are not linearly separable

Answer (score 0):

Since the classes are not linearly separable, one way to approach this classification problem is to use kernel tricks for predictions. Kernel tricks transforms the given input space into a high dimensional feature space where the data becomes separable.

Here are some links that could be of some help:

1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA

2) http://www.eric-kim.net/eric-kim-net/posts/1/kernel_trick.html

At first, kernel tricks might look complex for implementation. But, it is easy to implement and very powerful for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% true that kernels make every data linearly separable in a feature space. That depends on the data itself. For example, one data set encircled by another data set could be made linearly separable if we use an RBF kernel. If two sets fully overlap and consist of too many data points, finding a kernel to make them separable would be impossible!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer neural networks. They can be better implemented and are far more flexible than SVM in the sense that a “separation” (whether linear or not) is learned in the hidden layers without requiring from us to decide for a kernel (like in SVM). But again, everything depends on many factors such as the complexity of the data, the class balance, the quality of the targets (whether there are conflicting or not) and the like.